# multiple insert row if not exists (based on multiple columns)

Tags: mysql

Imagine an existing table with data (names are self explanatory):

`id`,`name`,`telephone_1`,`telephone_2`

i want to insert multiple new records with one `INSERT` (hopefully multiple new records with one insert -if thats a problem i could fall back to insert one-by-one), but i want a new row to be added ONLY if the `telephone_1` OR the `telephone_2` of the new record does NOT already exist **either** in `telephone_1` OR the `telehpone_2` of an existing record.

That means if we have existing data

`1, Jimmy, 123, 456`

i should not be able to add a

`NULL,John,444,123`

because John's `telephone_2` exists already as `telephone_1` of Jimmy.

I'm planning to let mysql do the heavy work instead of my program, but how can i do that? I have done something similar in the past using `UNIQUE` indexes, but the problem in this case is that the columns are 2. The `telephone_1` should not collide with `telephone_1` **and also** should not collide with `telephone_2` (and same for `telephone_2`)

UPDATE-CLARIFICATION: The data i'm trying to insert are not from another table; they are generated on the fly from my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table name is `contacts`, then try to insert record:

```
INSERT INTO contacts(name,telephone_1,telephone_2)
 SELECT 'John', 444, 123
 FROM contacts
 WHERE telephone_1 NOT IN (444, 123)
 AND telephone_2 NOT IN (444, 123)
 LIMIT 1;
```

Trick there: if WHERE condition is false then SELECT returns no rows and record is not inserted.

Try here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a6e0/1

Comment: @Sharky: small correction added `LIMIT 1;` to query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Insert into tableA select * from tableB where tableB.telephone_1 not in (select telephone_1 tableA union select telephone_2 tableA ) AND tableB.telephone_2 not in (select telephone_1 tableA union select telephone_2 tableA )
```

where

tableA is your main table where you want to insert new record.
tableB is other table from where you want to fetch record

Comment: there is no `TableB`, im getting data from my application.

Comment: @Sharky You may need to have a temporary table. Or it seems like you need some procedure.

Comment: @sri thank you for your answer, are subqueries the only way? is there something more elegant?

Comment: @Sharky You need to create temporary table in MySQL when you need to get data from your application. shri is right

Comment: @sharky Sub query is fast. You can use join also but I suggest use this sub query